# getline() in loop consuming constantly more memory in embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, getline

After running application over weekend I noticed in the morning that it was killed because no memory was left.

After commenting some parts of code, I see that this procedure might be a problem, but I can't figure out why.

```
void readData (char * path) {

// Reading and parsing config from file
FILE * fp;
size_t len = 0;
size_t read;

char *begin, *end, line[100], data[100];

fp = fopen(path, "r");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
/*      begin = strstr(line, "\"data\":[")+8;
        end = strstr(begin, "]");
        strncpy(data, begin,strlen(begin) - strlen(end));
        data[strlen(begin) - strlen(end)] = 0;
*/
        int tmp;

//      sscanf(data,"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&tmp,&ss.tensionRaw,&tmp,&tmp,&ss.depthRaw,&ss.speedRaw);
        ss.tension = cs.tensionCoeff * ss.tensionRaw;
        ss.speed   = cs.speedCoeff * ss.speedRaw;
        ss.depth   = cs.depthCoeff * ss.depthRaw;

/*      begin = strstr(line, "\"failedRequests\":\"")+18;
        end = strstr(begin, "\"");
        strncpy(data, begin,strlen(begin) - strlen(end));
        data[strlen(begin) - strlen(end)] = 0;
        ss.connectionOK = atoi(data);*/
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Can getline cause problems like this?
I monitor memory use of app by "top" and every 15-20 sec it gets around 4K more. When i comment whole while loop, it's not increasing.

Comment: First of all check type of `line` to `char*` .

Comment: Is it necessary to read line by line?

Answer (score 3):

The manual for [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) strongly hints that the line pointer is not a fixed buffer, but a pointer to an allocated string, since it states

> Alternatively, before calling **getline**(), *lineptr can contain a pointer
>   to a **malloc**(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not
>   large  enough  to  hold the line, **getline**() resizes it with **realloc**(3),
>   updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.

Comment: For completeness `getline()`'s Linux reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Dickey's answer (as edited by alk) is correct.

For sanity's sake, here's an example on how to properly read a file, line by line, using [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Read the named file line by line.
 * Returns 0 if successful,
 * nonzero (== errno) error code otherwise.
*/
int line_by_line(const char *const filename)
{
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    ssize_t len;
    long    linenum = 0L;
    FILE   *in;

    /* Invalid filename? */
    if (filename == NULL || *filename == '\0')
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Open file. If it fails, fopen() will set errno. */
    in = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if (in == NULL)
        return errno;

    /* Read loop. */
    while (1) {

        len = getline(&line, &size, in);
        if (len <= (ssize_t)0)
            break;

        linenum++;

        /* Note: if (strlen(line) < (size_t)len),
         *       the line contains embedded NUL (zero) bytes.
        */

        /*
         * Do something with the line ...
        */
        printf("%ld: %s", linenum, line);
    }

    /* Discard possibly used line buffer. Note: free(NULL) is safe. */
    free(line);

    /* I/O error? */
    if (!feof(in) || ferror(in)) {
        fclose(in);
        return errno = EIO;
    }
    if (fclose(in))
        return errno = EIO;

    /* All done successfully. */
    return 0;
}
```

However, if it does not look like the file is actually line-oriented data; that there is only one interesting record in the file at all. Who knows, it might be split to multiple lines, too.

Here's what I'd use for this case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t read_file(const char *const filename, char **const dataptr, size_t *const sizeptr)
{
    FILE   *in;
    char   *data;
    size_t  size, more;
    size_t  have = 0;

    /* Invalid parameters? */
    if (filename == NULL || *filename == '\0' || dataptr == NULL || sizeptr == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return (size_t)0;
    }

    /* If *dataptr is NULL, *sizeptr is assumed to be 0. */
    data = *dataptr;
    if (data != NULL)
        *sizeptr = 0;
    size = *sizeptr;

    /* Open file, read-only, in binary mode. If it fails, fopen() sets errno. */
    in = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (in == NULL)
        return (size_t)0;

    while (1) {

        /* Need to grow the data buffer?
         * (The +1 accounts for the end-of-buffer NUL byte). */
        if (have + (size_t)1 >= size) {

            /* Start with a 8k buffer.
             * Double it in size for up to 1M,
             * then round to next full megabyte. */
            if (size < 8190)
                size = 8192;
            else
            if (size < 1048576)
                size *= 2;
            else
                size = (size | 524287) + 524289;

            /* Size too large (wrapped)? */
            if (size <= *sizeptr) {
                free(data);
                fclose(in);
                *dataptr = NULL;
                *sizeptr = 0;
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return (size_t)0;
            }

            /* Reallocate. */
            data = realloc(data, size);
            if (data == NULL) {
                free(data);
                fclose(in);
                *dataptr = NULL;
                *sizeptr = 0;
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return (size_t)0;
            }

            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        /* Read more data, but remember to leave room for the
         * terminating NUL byte. */
        more = fread(data + have, 1, size - have - 1, in);
        if (more > (size_t)0)
            have += more;
        else
            break;
    }

    /* I/O error? */
    if (!feof(in) || ferror(in)) {
        free(data);
        fclose(in);
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
        errno = EIO;
        return (size_t)0;
    }
    if (fclose(in)) {
        free(data);
        fclose(in);
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
        errno = EIO;
        return (size_t)0;
    }

    /* Append terminating NUL byte; we reserved space for it. */
    data[have] = '\0';

    /* Technically we shouldn't need to set errno. */
    errno = 0;
    return have;
}

struct state {
    double  tensionCoeff;
    double  speedCoeff;
    double  depthCoeff;
    double  tension;
    double  speed;
    double  depth;
    double  tensionRaw;
    double  speedRaw;
    double  depthRaw;
    long    connectionOk;
};
#define STATE_INITIALIZER { 0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0, 0L }

static char   *state_buffer_data = NULL;
static size_t  state_buffer_size = 0;

static void free_state_buffer(void)
{
    free(state_buffer_data);
    state_buffer_data = NULL;
    state_buffer_size = 0;
}

#define UPDATED_TRIPLET (1U << 0)
#define UPDATED_CONN_OK (1U << 1)

unsigned int update_state(const char *const filename, struct state *const current)
{
    unsigned int retval = 0U;
    char        *data;
    size_t       len;

    if (current == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0U;
    }

    len = read_file(filename, &state_buffer_data, &state_buffer_size);
    if (!len) {
        if (errno == 0)
            errno = ENODATA;
        return 0U;
    }

    data = strstr(state_buffer_data, "\"failedRequests\":");
    if (data != NULL) {
        long conn_ok;
        if (sscanf(data+17, " %ld", &conn_ok) == 1) {
            current->connectionOk = conn_ok;
            retval |= UPDATED_CONN_OK;
        }
    }

    data = strstr(state_buffer_data, "\"data\":[");
    if (data != NULL) {
        double value[6];
        if (sscanf(data+8, " %lf , %lf , %lf , %lf , %lf , %lf ",
                   &(value[0]), &(value[1]), &(value[2]), 
                   &(value[3]), &(value[4]), &(value[5])) == 6) {
            current->tensionRaw = value[1];
            current->depthRaw = value[4];
            current->speedRaw = value[5];
            current->tension = current->tensionCoeff * current->tensionRaw;
            current->depth = current->depthCoeff * current->depthRaw;
            current->speed = current->speedCoeff * current->speedRaw;
            retval |= UPDATED_TRIPLET;
        }
    }

    /* All done. If the buffer is twice as large, or at least two megabytes larger
       than the amount of data we read, discard the buffer. */
    if ((state_buffer_size > len + len && len > 4095) ||
        state_buffer_size > len + 2048576)
        free_state_buffer();
    errno = 0;
    return retval;
}
```

This works just fine even if the data is spread on multiple lines. I'd perhaps use custom functions to find the data starting points (`strstr()` is too rigid, even an extra space here or there will throw it off).

The buffer is reused between `update_state()` calls, unless the new data is much smaller than the buffer size, in which case the buffer is discarded (and reallocated as needed during the next call), to keep memory overhead low. (However, note that most C library implementations do not return memory back to the OS, unless the allocations were originally large enough to use memory maps instead of sbrk().)

`update_state()` always sets errno, to zero if no errors occurred. Its return value is a bit mask of `UPDATED_` values; `(retval & UPDATED_CONN_OK)` is true if the failedRequests record was found, and `(retval & UPDATED_TRIPLET)` is true if the three numeric fields among the six first data fields were located and updated in the parameter structure.